# Shouldn't there be a language translation technique on the physics Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, language

As we know that the physics Stack Exchange site is an international website, there must be a language translation technique for non-English speakers as they face problems to express them freely.

Comment: More on [language](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language).

Comment: What sort of "translation technique" beyond what you can already do on your own - namely using Google Translate or similar services to translate something into English, then post the result here - are you imagining here?

Comment: Because this is an English language site, it should be the responsibility of the users to be able to communicate understandably in English.  I don't see why that would be up to the website.

Comment: Machine translation usually produces partly or totally incomprehensible results. Knowledge of the original language is usually required to understand/fix the translation.

Answer (score 5):

There simply are no such language translation tools $-$ technical language is too complicated, and machine translation is (intrinsically?) not good enough to handle it.

If you have any *specific* tool in mind that you'd like to propose, then you're obviously welcome to propose it. However, it is *your* job to go and research what tools there are out there, and to put forward a compelling case for why any individual tool you find should be added to the site.